Azure Application Insights in C# .NET Core
I'm using Application Insights configured for my application. You can refer to this documentationApplicatioInsight
Here is my code:
static TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration();

public static IHostBuilder UseSerilogCreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
            
              telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];                                   
              telemetryConfiguration.SetAzureTokenCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
         })
       .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
             .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
             .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces));

In the Application Insights dashboard, response codes are being logged. The error response codes (500, 401, and 400) and their counts are visible, but no detailed descriptions for these errors are displayed.
Here is the screenshot:
.
Expected failure or transaction log count along with description.

Click on drill into and check once

Are you authenticating your App ?

I always search in Transaction search blade instead of Availability blade to get the error/exception details.. Could you pls help check in that menu?

It means that SDK successfully submits metrics but not logs/spans. It can be caused by a few (mis)configurations - either on client (app) or ingestion sides. One (preferred) option is to open a support ticket. Another option is to send either instrumentation key or application id to  @ microsoft.com - I can try to look up for something obvious but will not be able to cover everything.

@Raghu Can you please provide your program.cs file and .net core version.

@Harshitha Yes I'm Authenticating my app.

@SirraSneha .net core version is 8.0

@Raghu I'm able to view detailed decryptions without any issues please check this

I created a sample ASP.NET core 8.0 Application and successfully configured authentication, can view traces and their detailed descriptions without any issues.
Make sure you install the latest versions of the below packages.
Serilog
Serilog.Sinks.Console
Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights

My program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug().
    .WriteTo.Console() 
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()   .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"], TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(); 
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{  
    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
    {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error;
       
            Log.Error(exception, "An unhandled exception occurred.");           
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Something went wrong.</h1>");
        });
    });
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();  
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
var logger = Log.ForContext("SourceContext", "Startup");
logger.Information("Application started successfully."); 
app.Run();

appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "MicrosoftFieldLedSandbox.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<Tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<client-id>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "<client-secret>",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": [
      "access_as_user"
    ]
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": { "connectionString": "<connection-string>" }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "<connection-string>"
  }
}

csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-example1insights-<your-ID> </UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Successfully authenticated my app

In my App insights I can view the traces and their detailed descriptions.


